# Sony RX100 M2 purple flare

Tags: lens-flare

[image: Purple flare.]
This is a shot of the flare. The size can vary depending on the angle away from the sun. Also the darkness varies depending on exposure, slightly more exposure = darker purple

Comment: First thing: are you using a filter?

Answer (score 1):

> Shots away from the sun are fine, it's only when shooting towards the sun at a slight angle away from it. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Sounds like it's just regular old lens flare. A lens hood is the usual solution, but since the RX100 is a compact camera with no attachment point for a hood, you could improvise some sort of tube, or just hold your hand up near the lens on the sunny side. If your shot actually includes the sun, then there's not a lot you can do to prevent the flare except to reframe the shot or edit the flare out later.

[Here's one example](https://flic.kr/p/drL1uh) of creative use of lens flare on a RX100 from flickr:

[image: rx100 lens flare]

Comment: Thanks Caleb, in this instance it's not the usual flare as you have described, and shown, although it is the same colour. It is a separate halo. I will be posting a photo later in the day

Comment: @Mick Your example is a more garden variety of flare than the one in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the RX100 suffers from a purple lens flare issue. But then, nearly any camera/lens combination, shooting into a light source, will exhibit flare. You can try shading the lens with your hand, or SteffanB on dpreview recommends opening up the aperture to eliminate the flare: (see [this post](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/42655279)).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have an RX 100 II, and the purple/blue spot has bit me a couple of times. It's an internal reflection flare that seems to affect the lens in any moderate / strong backlighting situation. It has nothing to do with off-axis light sources, so a lens hood will not help.

Sadly, there really isn't a fix except a different camera. Just be aware that the spot may loom in any backlit scene.